# Stop React Higher Order Component from mounting before wrapped component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have an auth-related HOC which wraps components. In the wrapped components, I want a user prop which is set by the HOC. However, in a child component I call the prop in componentDidMount, and I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'identity' of null
```

Which tells me that the user prop (which has the identity attribute) is not being set in time. 
Here is the HOC:

```
export default function withAuth(AuthComponent) {
    return class AuthWrapped extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                user: null
            };
            this.Auth = new AuthService();
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
            try {
                const profile = await this.Auth.getProfile(); //Returns a decoded JWT token containing with 'identity':'test'
                console.log(profile.identity); //prints 'test' twice
                this.setState({
                    user: profile
                });
                console.log(this.state.user); //prints the full profile including 'identity':'test' once and null once
            }
        }

        render() {
            const user = this.state.user;
            console.log(user); //prints null once and the correct profile once
            return (
                <AuthComponent history={this.props.history} user={this.state.user} />
            );
        }
    };

 }
```

Notice that the console.logs each print twice.
Here's the wrapped component:

```
class Account extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/user/' + this.props.user.identity).then(res => { //This is the line which triggers the error.
            //do something
        });
    }

    render() {
                <div><AnotherComponentWrappedBySameHOC/></div>
            );
        }
}

export default withAuth(Account);
```

When I remove the other component that is also wrapped by withAuth, the console.logs only run once. Makes sense. However, the logs which still print are the logs which print null. In other words, the wrong logs.

Basically, I think this means that the componentDidMount call in withAuth is taking too long, and completing after the componentDidMount call in Account. Try as I might, though, I have no solutions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wait untill you have the user and then render the child like

```
  render() {
            const user = this.state.user;
            console.log(user); //prints null once and the correct profile once
            return (<div>
               {user && <AuthComponent history={this.props.history} user={this.state.user} />}
            </div>);
        }
    };
```

This will only render the child component when `user` has some data

Comment: Totally rad, preciate it

Comment: Btw, your 'About me' is dope.

Comment: ahaha oh jeez thanks, but forgot about that--kind of embarrassing, probably will change it